# Question about sigma algebra generated by sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

let ($\Omega, S, P$) be a probability space and $X_1, X_2,.....$ be a sequence of a random variable. I know that if we have a random variable $X$ on probability space then the sigma-algebra generated by $X$ is $\sigma(X)$={$A\in \Omega$  such that $A=X^{-1}(B)$ for some $B\in B(\mathbb{R})$} where $B(\mathbb{R})$ is a Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.But I am not getting what the sigma-algebra generated by the sequence of random variables will look like. If anyone explains this that will be a great help for me also if you can give some examples to understand it more clearly?Thanks

Comment: $\sigma$-algebras are usually defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebras containing certain sets in $\Omega$. So here: $\sigma(X_1,X_2,...)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all $\sigma(X_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, one can define

$$ \sigma(X) := \{ A \subseteq \Omega : \exists B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), A = X^{-1}(B) \}. $$

Equivalently, this is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra s.t. the function $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable. Now, take a sequence of random variables $X_1, \ldots$, all defined on $\Omega$. Then the same philosophy applies and one defines $\sigma(X_1, \ldots)$ as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ such that all the $X_i$ are measurable functions.

As an example, let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $X_i(\omega) = \omega_i$, i.e. let $X_i$ be the $i$-th projection map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for every $0 \leq i \leq n$. Then the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is precisely the product $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

For (discrete) stochastic processes i.e. sequences of random variables $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ it is common to consider not only the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the entire sequence but all $\sigma$-algebras generated by truncated sequences, i.e. one considered the $\sigma$-algebras

$$ \mathcal{F}_{n} := \sigma( X_1, \ldots, X_n), ~~~ n \geq 0.$$

called the filtration generated by $X_1, \ldots$. For example, let $X_1, \ldots$ be a sequence of coin tosses i.e. functions $\Omega \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Then by the above definitions for every

$$ \mathcal{F}_n = \big\{ \{ \omega \in \Omega : X_1(\omega) = x_1, \ldots, X_n(\omega) = x_n \} (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \{0,1\}^n \big\} $$

i.e. $\mathcal{F}_n$ contains precisely those events that only involve the results of the first $n$ coin tosses.